# Where could you get a straight-on shot of only the sky?

Tags: sky

Is there any place on Earth you could stand where you could hold a camera directly forward (90degrees) and snap a picture and in the photo you would only see the sky?

I worry that even if you stood atop the tallest mountain in the world that you would still see ground at the bottom of your picture.

I'm interested in the idea of taking a pure full straight-on perspective photo of the sky.

Comment: You'd have to tell us what lens you'd be using, an 8mm fish-eye would be able to see your feet, let alone everything else; a 600mm birding lens you could just about do it from your bedroom window.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from any building that sticks up above surrounding buildings and trees. Or, you know, pretty much any boat on the ocean (and many large lakes). You just need a narrow enough field of view — which is to say, a lens with a relatively high focal length.

For example, here is a picture from a second-floor deck, with the lens parallel to the ground:

[image: mostly sky]

This is at a field of view corresponding to that of about a 400mm lens on a 35mm ("full frame") camera. Now, obviously, that's not *all sky*, but I'm in the most densely populated city in New England, so there's buildings all around. If you're somewhere with just a little more space, no problem. Or, use a slightly longer lens.

That said, presumably you want as wide-angle shot as possible. In that case, you're looking for a) height and b) flatness below. Cliffs along the ocean are a good way to get that — here's a [list of some of the most dramatic](http://www.touropia.com/most-dramatic-sea-cliffs-in-the-world/) — many of which look to be great tourist destinations. Kalaupapa in Hawaii, the cliffs of Moher in Ireland, Fira in Greece….

Comment: Of course, your plan basically involves shooting through the most air possible. Since "sky" is just… air… this may be fine. But if that's all you want, you could also take another approach: find a very foggy day anywhere in the world, and take a photograph of the sky that you're _in_.